# Protractor not locating testing spec files?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

For some reason, Protractor is not picking up the spec files specified in the conf.js file. As far as I can tell the path is correct - see screenshot below. Any ideas what I'm missing?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what is inside `EmailUs_spec.js`?

Comment: Hi alecxe - yes, essentially this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430320/looping-through-fields-in-an-angular-form-and-testing-input-validations-using-pr?rq=1

Comment: What if you move `specs` to under the first capability object under `multiCapabilities`?

Comment: Hi Alecxe - that didn't work - same 'No specs found' message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your folder structure and conf file are correct, the problem is with your spec file. The `it` block in your spec file is not correctly defined. If you put a simple test in your `EmailUs_spec.js` it will run.